# Trouble activating Timer in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm currently trying to create a service that will execute a metod every 14 days, (is 20 sec now, becasue of testing). I have currently these lines of code in my service and i cant seem to get it to run the AddDataToDb() metod. Anyone got any idea of what i can do to get the timer to work?

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer oTimer = null;
        double interval = 2000;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IntializeService();
        }

        void IntializeService()
        {
            oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
            oTimer.Enabled = true;
            oTimer.AutoReset = true;
            oTimer.Start();
            oTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(oTimer_Elapsed);


        }

        void oTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            Data.mData data = new mData();
            data.AddDataToDb();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            oTimer.Enabled = true;
            oTimer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            oTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a timer for a 14 day period is the wrong approach anyway because precision will be destroyed on every app deployment or reboot. Use the task scheduler.

Comment: And if i want it to run on a mvc site? Is the task scheduler still the best option?

Comment: Have the scheduler request a secret URL to trigger processing.

Comment: For starters you have used 2 secs (not 20 :)) and it's usually not good practice to wire the handler after you call start() in the InitializeService method. Nonetheless it makes no difference in the above code.  Can you further elaborate on what you mean by can't get the method to run? As in you have tried some debugging and the breakpoints don't get hit?

Comment: i'm not sure of what i say, but there are two kinda of thread, foregrounds , and backgrounds, and if the timer used (i think the background one), it only work till the process end, and wont continue after main thread, so the service may just stop after starting, because there is no more command to tell him to stop. i say this, because in Win App you see, that timer stop working when you close the form. so i think it's background.    it's just a test, as i said i'm not sure, but try to just hold your service for some minutes, and then with a fore/back ground thread for some, to see if it worked

Comment: also one more thing, timer is not valid on real time issue, it say it take (fore example 1000ms) to run your command for second time, but it doesn't mean the total time is 1000ms, it's :   
time before event run for second time is = your code execution time + 1000ms      so, use that event just to check Times, at little intervals, and then if it passed 14 days, then, handle it, also you can listen to other comments, i didnt used their ways

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is a pretty evil class.  One thing it does is swallow *all* exceptions when it fires the Elapsed event.  You *must* use try/except in your Elapsed event handler.  Log the error you get and stop the service when that happens.  And yes, the odds that you'll actually get 14 days out of that timer are not that good, you'll of course start back at 0 when the service restarts.